# Search for specific node in Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to search for specific nodes in AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). The basic idea is:

- There is an AST parsed from source code which contains about 10000 nodes.
- There is a list of 50 items that I would like to search in the AST.

Question: What is the best way to search for those 50 items in AST?

Right now, I am thinking about using Arraylist containing those 50 items. Then, traversing AST and compare each node with Arraylist using a loop. Is this good idea in term of performance? I want the operation to be done fast. Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Is "LOOP" an acronym? If so, what does it stand for?

Comment: I think he means using a (for)loop.

Comment: could you describe those 50 items you would like to search? are they somehow related with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an Arralylist, as it requires you scan across it each time and that's just overhead. You can write 50 predicates as "p1 or p2 or ...." just as easily.

You can either search the tree once, applying 50 predicates to decide if you have an interesting node, or search the tree 50 times, applying one predicate on each separate pass. In both cases, you have to run the predicates, so they don't change the cost (note below) either way.

If you search-once, you'll need to "or" together the answers of the 50 predicates, needing 49 ors,  so the additional cost is 49*[cost of OR]*[number of nodes]. If you search-50, the additional cost is 49*[cost to visit tree node]*[number of nodes].  So, the question is whether the cost of "or" is less than the cost of "visit tree node".   "Or" is pretty fast on most machines, because it only uses registers and values already probably in the cache.  Visiting a tree node can be pretty fast, but is likely several instructions; worse, it touches memory.  If your tree is big enough to not fit in the cache, your search-50 cost will likely dominated by memory access times, if the predicates are cheap.

Now, we can "cheat" in some interesting ways.  First, it may be the predicates have some relationships; if predicate A implies predicate B, I can check for B first, and if false, I don't have to test for A. That can cut the number of "or", but doesn't help with tree visits.  Secondly, it may be that predicates share subtests, e.g., predicate A is really "a1 and a2", and B is actually "a1 and a2"; in this case, you can factor the predicates and evaluate the sub-predicates fewer times; you only need to evaluate "a1" once per node.  That's not so easy do with scan-multiple technique.  It may be that some predicate failure implies a subtree need not be searched; here the 50 searches may turn out to be faster as each search will only check the necessary subtrees, where the search-once will pretty much require searching down to a node that *all* predicates agree is a stopping point.

However, it is likely that for each predicate, your program will want to react differently. So your program structure is really a set of  "if p1(node) then a1(node)".  If the predicates are cheap and trigger with relatively high frequency, the actions are likely to be a dominating cost (more expensive than navigating a tree node), and then either technique will be fine in terms of performance.

Finally, if the predicates and actions are complex, you simply might not be able to guess which one is cheaper, easily.  Fine, code both searches ( isn't *that* hard) and measure it on realistic data.